# Toggle Bolts you don't need to screw into?

Tags: anchor, fastener

I need to attach a bronze piece to some stainless steel with no back access, the bronze piece has two all-thread rods coming out of the back to insert into matching holes in the stainless. Originally there were nuts to secure in the back but I can no longer access the back panel. Does a toggle bolt or anchor exist where I could just hammer the rods in, as I cannot screw them in?

[image]

Comment: This is the best site to ask this question, but if you don't get an answer here within a few days, you might try again at [Lifehacks Stack Exchange](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: It might also help if you added the size and weight of the bronze piece to the question.

Comment: Can you post some pictures?  Can the stainless steel be removed from what it is on?  Is there a way to turn the rods in the bronze piece?

Comment: Stainless steel is mounted on a corten steel base, it was recommended to cut an access panel in that but would like to avoid. The bronze weighs about 5 pounds and the rods are fixed in the back to feed through the stainless, no way to turn them. I added a plan view cross section

Comment: Does the bronze thing need to be attached permanently, or do you want the ability to take it off again?

Comment: How secure does it have to be? Can you just hang it on a hook or something, or do you need a stronger connection?

Comment: The surface that you're attaching it to - is it vertical? In the drawing it seems to be at an angle, but I don't know if that's an accurate representation of what you have.

Comment: It's at about a 45 degree angle and the more permanent the better. The last one was stolen so trying to avoid that

Comment: This is a tough one, being unable to spin the threaded rods. If this gets closed here, consider to post in Engineering SE, as it certainly is an engineering quandry.

Comment: Thanks @fred_dot_u

Comment: A push nut would do the "no need to spin" part, but unless you captured them to the back of the stainless *before* you immutably mounted the stainless to the cor-ten without back access, you're not going to be able to do that.

Comment: Is the stainless steel thick enough to tap for threads?  If not, you could use a nutsert/rivnut. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJ4gF2tXRBE

Comment: Drill holes into the steel to use the brass allthread for positioning, and epoxy the brass piece to the steel surface.

Answer (score 6):

Given the hole you appear to have backed youself into, "glop some thick epoxy through the holes, slather more on the rods and back of the thing, and depend on adhesives to hold it" appears to be the workable "solution" without cutting access.

A more complex approach that might be more secure would be to drill out the holes larger, at a tap size for a large threaded rod. The rod would be large enough that you could have a machine shop bore a hole through the center a bit bigger than your small threaded rod. They could also weld push nuts onto the far end, but the main advantage would be a much larger area to apply epoxy to for bonding the smaller rods in place.

Or cut an access hole, use normal nuts and lockwashers and threadlocker, then weld the access hole closed if vandals are your issue. If they are harvesting bronze for the scrapyard that may not work, as they can still break the thing with a sledgehammer and haul the broken parts away. The perils public art is subject to...

Comment: If this is a permanent installation, then epoxy is the way to go. It should be much more durable than anything you can rig up with threaded fasteners. It's also much simpler than any alternatives.